# "Limit selection to visible" not working

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, transparency, selection-tools

[image: Testing selection visible functionality]

I just downloaded Blender 2.79 after about 8 months of not using the software. I noticed that the "selection visible" function isn't working. I expect it to make the mesh partially transparent, but as of now, it does nothing. I am not sure what is going on. Thanks in advance for the help:)

Comment: could you share your file?

Comment: I put it into a Zip folder on my Google drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pR62an4e6xXuHBREr8J75DhJVq0AnTDI/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

Oh that was a tricky one...

it's just because you have collapsed the actual horizontal bottom bar of your 3D window, and the one we see is actually from another 3D window that you also have collapsed

so grip the bottom of your 3D windows and pull it up, them display its real bottom menu bar with the small "+" on the bottom right

and now you can activate the Limit Selection to Visible button

[image]

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I would have never gotten that in a million years

Comment: ah ah  ;)  in this kind of situation you could have opened a new file and made an Append of your cube, or a copy paste if you have two versions of Blender... you would have not solved the problem for this specific problem though